# GIT - how to approach repositories and where can I find my branches after making them

Tags: git

It's my first day with GIT, so I have a few basic questions.

1) Let's assume I have one folder called "Projects" and inside there are 20 different projects for different clients and so on. Among them "Project-1" and "Project-2".

Where should I establish my repository? "Projects" or should I make a repository out of each folder separately?

2) Ok, I made a repo. Now I want to make a branch, I succeed. Now where can I see my branch files? I'm expecting to have different folders in the repo - with the master branch and the others that I create along the way.

Comment: Different folders for different branches! **Stupid SVN**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's common practice to have separate Git repositories for different projects. This means you can develop on each project individually and not worry about overwriting changes you made to one project, if you have to revert a change to another.

2) If you are new to Git, I wouldn't worry about branches for the time being. If you do create a branch, you won't see them in a separate folder. The magic which keeps track of your branches is hidden away in your .git folder in each repository.

You can see which branch you are on by typing `git branch`. You can view all branches with `git branch -a`.

Comment: Thank you, that explains a lot. Just to make it clear (I have to be working with branches already):

Let's say I have two branches - "master" and "alternate".

I do: `git checkout alternate` and add a line in file.txt (I don't commit it). 

Then i do: `git checkout master`, open that file again - why do I see the changes if I'm on master?

I would assume I can open 2 versions of the file.txt in my editor and see the differences, but it doesn't seem to be working that way.

Comment: If you wanted to switch back to master and overwrite your local state, you would use ```git checkout -f -b branchname```. This will checkout the master version of your repo, and overwrite any files on your file system which do not match. Be careful with this though as it is possible to lose changes you have made. If you want to keep any changes, be sure to commit them to the current branch before switching. You can also just use ```git checkout filename``` to revert a single file so that it matches the version in the current branch.

Comment: @oneday If you commit the change on the alternate branch and chen checkout the master branch you won't see the new code. However, changes that are not staged will move between branches because they aren't attached to a particular branch. If you want to checkout a different branch without committing the changes I would suggest stashing the changes before switching branches.

Comment: All right, I just saw that the commited changes are not visible between branches while the non-commited are. Ok, that explains a lot, thnx!

Answer (score 3):

You're clearly coming to git from svn, or something *like* svn.

In svn, everything is based around folders - branches, tags and repositories all become folders; each sub folder in your repo is could effectively be its own repo and so on.

That model of version control is, in my experience, unique to svn. You can't apply the same model elsewhere.

Git, in particular, is based around *commits* (actually, object, where a commit is a type of object, but for an easier mental model to get started, lets just think about commits)

Your repository is a tree of commits. Unlike svn, a commit can have more than one parent.

Git is also distributed, unlike svn, and this distinction is important even if you use it in a centralised repository type way. When you push and pull in git, you're just synchronising the tree of commits you have with some remote tree of commits.

Whereas in svn you have a repository, and you have a working copy locally, in git, you clone the repository. What you have locally is a repository in it's own right that can have it's own commits and branches and that other people can clone.

So to (finally) get to your questions:

1. The idea of having a single repository for multiple projects comes about because in svn there is typically no difference between a sub directory and a different repository. This isn't true of git, and you absolutely should have a separate repository for each project.
2. In git, a branch is just a label applied to a particular commit in the tree of commits for the project. The commits, labels and such are squirrelled away somewhere in `.git` in the root of your repository; it's typically not helpful to look at these files directly, and instead use a command like `git branch` to list branches or `git checkout` to change branches.

If you want to get a deeper understanding of how git works, I'd recommend reading a little of [Git from the inside out](https://codewords.recurse.com/issues/two/git-from-the-inside-out). It's not necessary to *use* git, but I find having a reasonably accurate mental model of what git does under the covers makes it's behaviour less surprising.

Comment: Your intuition is in place, I've worked with svn before as you assumed :) must have acquired the svn kind of logic and hence the lack of understanding.

Ok, thanks so much, this makes it even clearer.

Comment: It's not *completely* unique to svn, and some people occasionally use DVCSes like Mercurial this way (some Mercurial tutorials actively encourage "new clone for new branch"; it's conceptually simple and because hg shares the underlying files via hard links, does not even take that much space). But yes, Git is a mind-twister after using most other VCSes. :-)